# Is it possible to build a maven project on one java version and run it on another java versions?

Tags: java, maven

I am new to maven projects. I am curious to know that is it possible to build my maven project on JAVA version 1.8 and run it on JAVA version 11. In simple word, can I compile or build a maven project on JDK 1.8 and run it on JRE 11?

Comment: as JeroenHoek described in his answer it is possible. However, I would strongly recommend against it if you are developing business software. develope and compile against the exact java version (and vendor, e.g. oracle, openjdk, etc.) that your programm will run against.

Comment: The very simple answer to your question is: Yes. Build with JDK 8 and run on JDK11 ... that's backward compatibility. You can even build with JDK 8 and run on JDK16...Usually if you run on new JDK's your app will be faster..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Newer JDKs can run older bytecode, so if you compile for Java 8, you can, usually, run it on Java 11. Sometimes changes in the Java API or support for the newer Java runtime in your dependencies may necessitate changes in your code though.

Conversely, you can also use Maven to configure the compiler to output Java 8 bytecode while using a Java 11 JDK yourself in the `<plugins>` section of your Maven build:

```xml
      <plugin>
        <!-- Configure the compiler. -->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Note that this 'release' parameter was introduced in JDK 9. -->
          <release>8</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

What you cannot do though, is compile Java 11 bytecode using JDK 8. If you want to generate Java 11 bytecode and use newer Java features introduced after Java 8, just install a JDK 11 release on your development machine.

As noted by [meaningqo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68558402/is-it-possible-to-build-a-maven-project-on-one-java-version-and-run-it-on-anothe#comment121162616_68558402) in the comments above, you are generally better of developing and building on the same major Java version as your target environment unless you need to target multiple (major) Java versions. Java is backwards compatible, but there are always quirks that can trip you up, and if you have any dependencies in your project you may find that these do not always work in a newer Java version even if they run fine on Java 8, or that you need a newer version of that dependency for Java 11 that won't work with Java 8.

Comment: That's true but unfortunately it is exactly the opposite of what the original poster wanted to know.

Comment: That's why paragraph two starts with 'conversely'. The answer is in the first paragraph.